# Typescript: Get value type of Enum

Tags: typescript, enums

```
enum Test {A,B};
const x = { name:"Test", value:Test.B };
const y = typeof x.Value;
```

The value of y is "Number", May I know it is possible to get Test of type?

Comment: You assign type to a variable (`y`) and expect it to containt the type information? Types are erased during compilation, this would never work. Instead, assign type to type to have the type information at the compile time.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` in a value position is a javascript operator, not a typescript one. It always returns the same union of string literals at the type level.

```
const test = typeof false
// "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF44E8AO8QDMY4EMAbCeAKAHoKYaYA9AfiA)

But at runtime, `a.value` is just a number.

```
enum Test {A,B};
const a = { name: "Test", value: Test.B }
console.log(a.value) // 1
```

So `typeof a.value` is `'number'` because `typeof 1` is `'number'`.

Which means that at runtime, you cannot get a reference to an an enum which you only have a member of that enum. The member does not encode any information about where it came from.

---

But that's what your types are for.

You can use `typeof` in a type declaration to get the Typescript type of a any value. *This a totally different operator*.

```
enum Test {A,B};
const a = { name: "Test", value: Test.B }
type B = typeof a['value'] // Test
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXKBvAggGgEIF8DcAUAMYD2ISUAhlALypQiUTABcUARHEuxlAG6UANmFawEiAHRYoOAogCeAB2BRpdBcpIAzKgG0A5AOHB9AXQIB6C1BsA9APxA)

---

Without more details about your goal, I can't rally give any more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a **real object at runtime**, which means it is object defined as
**const**.

In this case, Test is a [numeric enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums).

```
typeof Test
{
   "0": "A",
   "1": "B",
   "A": 0,
   "B": 1
}
```